# The image of $\emptyset$ under $f$ is empty.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let A= $\{ \emptyset,\{1\},\{2,\},...,\{n\} \}$. Define $f\colon A \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(\emptyset)=0$ and $f(\{n\})=n$.

Is this a counterexample that the image of the $\emptyset$ under an arbitrary function $f$ is empty?

Comment: No, because the statement that $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ is given in a completely different context.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by both your notation and your question. $f$ is completely out of context so "is this a counterexample" I guess if you define it that way? Why call that a counterexample though?

Comment: One equation is talking about the image of a subset of the domain under $f$, while another equation is talking about where $f$ sends a particular element of the domain. Some sources use different notation for evaluation at elements versus images of sets in order to avoid this ambiguity. In particular, they would say $f[\varnothing]=\varnothing$ and $f(\varnothing)=0$, which makes clear there is no contradiction.

Comment: No, it is an example.

Comment: I amswered this to a friend, and gave me that as a counter example.

Suppose there is a $y \in f[\emptyset]$, then there is an $x \in \emptyset$ such that $f(x)=y$ (Since we are taking the image of empty under f) And this is a clear contradiction, as $x \in \emptyset$ is absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining  a function on a set $X$ that has $\emptyset$ *as an element*. So $f(\emptyset)$ can be anything you like.

But you're probably thinking of the notion of "image of a subspace under $f$".

I (and many texts/papers) always separate these notions notationwise, using square brackets so $f[\emptyset] = \emptyset$ which is indeed always true, and in general $$f[A]= \{y : \exists x \in A: f(x) = y\}$$ is used for the set of $f$-images of elements of $A$. Clearly, if $A$ has no elements, there are also no $f$-images. Some texts write $f(A)$ for $f[A]$ but this can get confusing, as witnessed by your question.